# Impact of Manifest V2 deprecation on my published extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I Have some spreadsheet extensions (editor add-ons) for my personal use, and i received email with following subject line: "**Impact of Manifest V2 deprecation on your published extensions**" which tells me that i have to **migrate my extension from manifest V2 to manifest V3**.

i gone through their migration guide provided on this link: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate, which took me to [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate/manifest) which tells me to do the changes in my "**manifest.json**" file.

apps script i am using to build this extension has "**appsscript.json**" file but i am not able to find "**manifest.json**" file anywhere. i also checked on cloud console where i update version number and scopes, but i didn't found anything about "manifest.json" there also.

so my questions are:

1. Is my google spreadsheet extension really need to this "upgrade action" ? or i just received email because i have listed it on chrome web store ?
2. If my extension require this upgrade, then where to find this "manifest.json" file ?

Comment: Looks like a mistake.